# Centralization of equations after using \begin {equation} and begin {split}

Tags: equations, amsmath

I'm having trouble centralizing my equations after using `\begin{equation}` and `\begin{split}`, they are always aligned to the right, I don't understand why.

```
\documentclass[
% -- opções da classe memoir --
12pt,               % tamanho da fonte
oneside,            % para impressão apenas no recto. Oposto a twoside
a4paper,            % tamanho do papel. 
]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\varDelta ^ {q_{\tau}} = q_{\tau}\left(F_{y_{p}|k=p}\right)-q_{\tau}\left(F_{y_{\alpha}|k=\alpha}\right) \\
\varDelta^{q_{\tau}}=\left[q_{\tau}\left(F_{y_{p}|k=p}\right)-q_{\tau}\left(F_{y_{p}|k=\alpha}\right)\right]+\left[q_{\tau}\left(F_{y_{p}|k=\alpha}\right)-q_{\tau}\left(F_{y_{\alpha}|k=\alpha}\right)\right]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

When I try, the formulas are centralized:

```
\documentclass[
% -- opções da classe memoir --
12pt,               % tamanho da fonte
oneside,            % para impressão apenas no recto. Oposto a twoside
a4paper,            % tamanho do papel. 
]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
A = \frac{\pi r^2}{2} \\
= \frac{1}{2} \pi r^2
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I also tried using `\begin{align}`, but it didn't work either:

```
\documentclass[
% -- opções da classe memoir --
12pt,               % tamanho da fonte
oneside,            % para impressão apenas no recto. Oposto a twoside
a4paper,            % tamanho do papel. 
]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\varDelta^{q_{\tau}}=q_{\tau}\left(F_{y_{p}|k=p}\right)-q_{\tau}\left(F_{y_{\alpha}|k=\alpha}\right) \nonumber \\
\varDelta^{q_{\tau}}=\left[q_{\tau}\left(F_{y_{p}|k=p}\right)-q_{\tau}\left(F_{y_{p}|k=\alpha}\right)\right]+\left[q_{\tau}\left(F_{y_{p}|k=\alpha}\right)-q_{\tau}\left(F_{y_{\alpha}|k=\alpha}\right)\right] \nonumber \\
\varDelta^{q_{\tau}}=\varDelta_{X}^{q_{\tau}}+\varDelta_{S}^{q_{\tau}}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I would like to know what the problem is. Thanks.

Comment: You could use `gathered` instead of `split`.

Comment: align and split are for _aligned_ equations (usually aligning on =)  so the syntax is `leftside &= right side`  as you have no `&` you only had left hand side so it right aligns towards the missing =.  Aff `&` before each `=` or use an unaligned enviornment such as `gather`

Comment: @NBur `equation` uses left or centred alignment depending on the document or package options, `\displaystyle` affects aspects of the the math layout but does not affect the horizontal alignment such as centering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to align at the equals sign:

```
\documentclass[
% -- opções da classe memoir --
12pt,               % tamanho da fonte
oneside,            % para impressão apenas no recto. Oposto a twoside
a4paper,            % tamanho do papel.
]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\varDelta^{q_{\tau}}&= q_{\tau}(F_{y_{p}\mid k=p})-q_{\tau}(F_{y_{\alpha}\mid k=\alpha}) \\
\varDelta^{q_{\tau}}&=[q_{\tau}(F_{y_{p}\mid k=p})-q_{\tau}(F_{y_{p}\mid k=\alpha})]
                     +[q_{\tau}(F_{y_{p}\mid k=\alpha})-q_{\tau}(F_{y_{\alpha}\mid k=\alpha})]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, in this case, I'd remove the second instance of `\varDelta^{q_{\tau}}`:

```
\documentclass[
% -- opções da classe memoir --
12pt,               % tamanho da fonte
oneside,            % para impressão apenas no recto. Oposto a twoside
a4paper,            % tamanho do papel. 
]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\varDelta^{q_{\tau}}
&= q_{\tau}(F_{y_{p}\mid k=p})-q_{\tau}(F_{y_{\alpha}\mid k=\alpha}) \\
&=[q_{\tau}(F_{y_{p}\mid k=p})-q_{\tau}(F_{y_{p}\mid k=\alpha})]
 +[q_{\tau}(F_{y_{p}\mid k=\alpha})-q_{\tau}(F_{y_{\alpha}\mid k=\alpha})]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the equations to be separately centered, but I don't think it's your aim, replace `split` by `gathered` and remove `&` to get

[image]

I removed all `\left` and `\right` commands, that serve no purpose here and actually spoil the final output.